# Unable to use 'NSKeyValueObservation' in Swift Docker 5.1.3

Tags: swift, docker, swift-package-manager

I am attempting to use NSKeyValueObservation in a Swift executable I am running on Docker. I am using the following swift version: 5.1.3

I stripped down everything and I literally just declare in main.swift:

```
var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

The error returned is:

```
/package/Sources/TestPackage/main.swift:30:19: error: use of undeclared type 'NSKeyValueObservation'
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

Since the error does not occur locally, my hunch is that Docker is running linux and linux doesn't know about NSKeyValueObservation but this isn't documented anywhere. If so, how do I get around this issue?

The relevant Docker version information is:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:34 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:29:19 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch is correct.  `NSKeyValueObservation` relies on the Objective-C runtime, which does not exist on non-Darwin platforms.  You will need to use an alternative, such as some flavor of Rx.